# Facing issue "Lexical Preprocessor Issue" XCode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9, thermal-printer

I am working on a Bluetooth application. I am using this Printer Framework. But I am facing "Lexical Preprocessor Issue". The file framework is present in the code still not working. I deleted the file and again added it but still no luck. Tried many things but unable to fix the issue. Please check the screenshot attached

[image]

Please help guys

Comment: How you are rectified this issue ? . I have same issue for a frame work'

Comment: @VineeshTP not yet. Facing the same issue. Let me know once you figure it out.

Comment: Are you using pods ?

Comment: No. Just framework !

Comment: Add path to framework searchpath.

Comment: Yes. I have tried it. Still doesn’t work.

Comment: If you are using Objc code along with Swift. import the file in Swift-Bridge file

Comment: Tried adding the bridging header, now it gives the error in bridging header, No such file found.

Comment: if you are using pods, please update it.

Comment: No pods! Just framework!

Comment: Have you copy the QuickBlox.framework ?

Comment: Printerlibs.framework

Comment: sorry I istakenly added QuickBlox.

Comment: Any solution ? For the framework I am using ?

Comment: remove and add again. then clean the project.

Comment: I have tried each and everything still it’s giving error. Don’t know what’s the reason.